# Editing files with Sublime Text 3 slow over SSHFS

Tags: sublime-text-3, sshfs, sublime-text, fuse

*This post was originally [posted on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30237796/editing-files-with-sublime-text-3-slow-over-sshfs), where users recommended reposting here.*

I'm currently mounting remote server directories as local folders under OS X 10.10.3 and OSXFUSE + SSHFS. When trying to edit these files with Sublime Text 3, simple edit operations are very slow. Even typing in characters has a 1-2 second delay before the characters appear in the document. Opening new files sometimes causes ST3 to hang for a minute.

In contrast, when opening the same files in vim (locally, on the SSHFS mount), editing them, and saving, I encounter no delays or problems.

Is there some reason I am encountering this slowness from ST3? How come vim does not encounter the same problems, in the same setting. Are there some configuration options I can set to avoid this? If the problem is plugin related, is there some way of troubleshooting which plugin is causing the bad behaviour?

I tried setting `"atomic_save": false` in my config, as suggested in some other StackOverflow posts. This helped a little, but there are still lag problems, so it did not completely resolve the issue.

Comment: Do you have a Git related plugin installed? Those are especially slow via SSHFS.

Answer (score 0):

For future reference, the comment by [nh2](https://superuser.com/users/150943/nh2) in OPs post was helpful for me. The following did the trick:

```
"ignored_packages":
[
    "GitGutter"
],
```

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was to disable indexing: after a restart it worked like a charm:

```
{
    "index_files": false
}
```